# Why don't some of my devices connect to internet and yet some don't?

Tags: ethernet, home-networking, cable, gigabit-ethernet, cabling

So I have run 4 wire ethernet throughout my house and I can't connect to the internet on my ps4 and some other devices on the socket in my main room but am able to do so through my laptop. Is it because of my ethernet cable ?

Comment: Proper Ethernet is 8 wire (4 twisted pairs).  If you only used 4 wire cable, it is probably not appropriate for some devices.

Comment: See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55572/rj45-cable-only-has-4-wires T568B is the most popular standard, rather than A.

Comment: ok so this thread answers everything https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55572/rj45-cable-only-has-4-wires